# YUV420 image conversion in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, image-processing

I wrote a flutter function for processing the Phones Camera preview image into RGB. It works for most devices I tested so far. But for one device (Nokia X10) the resulting image looks weird and I dont know what I am doing wrong. This is how the processed camera images look like. The proper looking one is from my Samsung phone and the wrong looking one was obtained running the code on the Nokia phone.

[image: Samsung after yuv420 processing]
[image: Nokia after Yuv420 processing]

I verified that the Camera Images returned for both of the phones uses [YUV420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888).

This is my yuv converting code:

```dart
  static img.Image convertYUV420toImageColor(CameraImage image) {
    try {
      final int width = image.width;
      final int height = image.height;
      final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
      final int? uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel;
      myLogger.d(image.planes[0].bytesPerRow); // nokia: 512, samsung: 320
      myLogger.d(image.planes[0].bytesPerPixel); // 1 for both phones
      myLogger.d(image.planes[1].bytesPerRow); // nokia: 512, samsung: 320
      myLogger.d(image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel); // 2 for both phones
      myLogger.d(image.planes[2].bytesPerRow); // nokia: 512, samsung: 320
      myLogger.d(image.planes[2].bytesPerPixel); // 2 for both phones

      // imgLib -> Image package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image
      var img2 = img.Image(width:width, height:height); // Create Image buffer

      for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
          final int uvIndex =
              uvPixelStride! * (x / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (y / 2).floor();
          final int index = y * width + x;

          final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
          final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
          final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
          // Calculate pixel color
          int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
          int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91)
              .round()
              .clamp(0, 255);
          int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);
          img2.setPixelRgba(x, y, r, g, b, 255);
        }
      }

      return img.copyRotate(img2, angle: 90); //Image.memory(png);
    } catch (e) {
      Log.logger.d("ERROR: " + e.toString());
    }
    throw Exception("error during YUV420 conversion");
  }
```

I was under the impression that any YUV420_888 conversion would work with my code but my tests show this is not the case. I am unable to find a difference in the image format specified between the two devices.

What am I doing wrong here? I am not even sure what paramater could be the reason for the wrong conversion. I thought YUV420_888 is a fixed definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
The culprit was this line

```dart
final int index = y * width + x;
```

where I wrongly assumed `width` to be always equal to `image.planes[0].bytesPerRow`
but the values shown in my question already point out that they can be different (512 vs 320).

The additional length is a padding that needs to be correctly adjusted when converting the image. If this is not done the stripes will appear since the processing uses wrong y values.

Simply correcting the calculation to

```dart
final int bytesPerRowY = image.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
final int index = y * bytesPerRowY + x;
```

solved the issue!